# in c# how to get filenames in dropdown without the full path

Tags: c#, dropdown

I want the list of files in a folder to be populated into my dropdown list.

in c# i use this to get filenames into dropdown:

```
private void CasparRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\JoZee\Desktop\Energy\Caspar\Server\media\");

        foreach (string name in fileArray)
        {
            cbxV1.Items.Add(name);
        }
```

How to i get only the filenames without the full path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Path.GetFileName()` method on the output of `Directory.GetFiles()`

```
   string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\JoZee\Desktop\Energy\Caspar\Server\media\");

    foreach (string name in fileArray)
    {
        cbxV1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(name));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another option to do same:

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\JoZee\Desktop\Energy\Caspar\Server\media\");
foreach (var fileInfo in dirInfo.GetFiles())
{
    cbxV1.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name);
}
```